# Incrementing progressbar during a delayed call

Tags: android, progress-bar, runnable, postdelayed

I have a delayed call which looks like this:

```
handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() { 
            public void run() {
                newDeviceBluetooth();
            //increment progressbar each thousand millis passed
            }
       },15000);
```

However I've got a fully functional progressbar that I want to increase with each second passed by the delay.
So what is the approach on this problem, is it a way to implement this?

Appreciate the time you take to answer and help me

---

So after I had a look at what was possible from the answers I wrote my own class that implements runnable. Is this a possible way to implement this? Think I kinda got it wrong if my gut feeling isn't messing around.

```
    public void run() {
    while(counter <= 15){
        if(counter < 15){
            handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    counter++;
                }
            }, 1000);
        }
        else{
            sb.newDeviceBluetooth();
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: What's the purpose of "if(counter < 15)"? 
That while will stop at 14 so there's no way counter will be equal or more than 15.

Comment: Sloppy code added, corrected it now! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found an answer to the problem. There's a sample code in the api demos under App/dialog/Progress dialog

So the code below needs to be modified but it displays a delay of the progressbar.

```
        mProgressHandler = new Handler() {
        @Override
        public void handleMessage(Message msg) {
            super.handleMessage(msg);
            if (mProgress >= MAX_PROGRESS) {
                mProgressDialog.dismiss();
            } else {
                mProgress++;
                mProgressDialog.incrementProgressBy(1);
                mProgressHandler.sendEmptyMessageDelayed(0, 100);
            }
```

Answer (score 3):

Is is possible for you to use AsyncTask instead? Then you can call publishProgress() and update the UI in onProgressUpdate()

Maybe it's not the best solution since it would require another thread.

---

But you can make your Runnable fire every second. You can do that by having the run() method do a postDelayed() to your handler.

Make your own class that extends runnable, and use a member variable for a counter.
In the normal case update the UI, and call newDeviceBluetooth() on the 15th time.

Comment: Edited my post, have a look from ::EDIT::